# c++ algorithm to select two random numbers from a range, with minimal distance

Tags: c++

I have an std::vector initialized with numbers from 1 to 100

```
std::vector<int> vec;
for(int i = 1; i < 101; i++)
  vec.push_back(i);
```

I want to select two random integers that have a minimal distance (for example minimal distance can be 10).

If num1, num2 are the numbers:

> num2 - num1 > distance

I am using the following method to select a random integer between ranges:

```
int getRandomValue(int from, int to)
        {
                std::random_device seeder;
                std::mt19937 engine(seeder());
                std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(from, to);
                return dist(engine);
        }
```

How can I generate num2 and num1?

Comment: Use the same approach but then `[0, std::numeric_limits<int>::max]` ?

Comment: 1) Select dist `D = 5` 2) Select random index `A = 
 rand(0 to (N - D))` 3) Select index `B = A + D`

Comment: Do you want a fixed distance or a minimal?  Your question asks for both.

Comment: @NathanOliver thank you. I need a minimal distance. I will update

Comment: OT: You probably want your mt to be `static` or `thread_local` so you don't have to reseed at every call. Otherwise, you could just use the `random_device` directly if you are calling it all the time anyways. Also, the seeding can be improved to see the entire state space of the mt, see e.g. my question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/109260/seed-stdmt19937-from-stdrandom-device).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use something like the following:

```
num1 = getRandomValue(minRange, maxRange - distance - 1);
num2 = getRandomValue(num1 + distance + 1, maxRange);
```

Note though that it would not be an uniform distribution for the pair result.

Comment: Your code does not work for the edge case.   if `num1 == maxRange-distance` then `num2 = maxRange`.    That does not satisfy the `num2-num1 > distance`.  Suggest `num1 = getRandomValue(minRange, maxRange-distance-1)` and `num2 = getRandomValue(num1 + distance + 1, maxRange)`.

Comment: apologies, the distance should be minimal 10 and not fixed

Comment: @Peter, that's right -1 and +1 are needed to satisfy corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

you can randomize num1 per example and sum the distance, then you have num2.

But you have to be careful cause num1 must be below or equal 100-distance

or the oposite randomize num2 from 10 to 100 and num1 = num2-distance

Comment: apologies, the distance has to be minimal and not fixed

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib>

a = rand() % 90;
b = a + 10;
```

a is the smaller , b is the bigger

Comment: The OP wants a minimal range of 10.  This gives them a fixed range.